# VB routine to locate and classify repeat events in date/time log

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a table in Access that logs the patient id, date/time, and doctor name for a particular medical procedure. I need to come up with a way to identify and classify repeat tests performed on the same day and apply a code accordingly. I'd like to find a way to update the code field automatically, rather than have someone do it manually (which is how it's currently being done, which can be very error prone!). My table is similar to the following.

```
Patient_id  Test_date_time      Doctor id    Code
----------  ------------------  ---------    -------
123         4/2/2012  08:00 AM  SMITH_J
123         4/2/2012  12:01 PM  SMITH_J     
123         4/3/2012  11:00 AM  SMITH_J
123         5/1/2012  10:00 AM  SMITH_J
123         5/1/2012  07:00 PM  SMITH_J
123         5/1/2012  08:00 PM  JONES_B
123         5/1/2012  10:00 PM  SMITH_J
```

I need to update the table based on the following criteria:

Make the code = 76 for all repeat procedures performed on the same day by the same doctor (but leave code blank for the first test on a particular day).

Make the code = 77 for repeat procedures performed on the same day, but by a different doctor (but again leave the code for the first occurrence blank).

Put another way, search the log to find all instances where a patient had a test performed on the same day, and make the code for these repeat procedures a 76 if the doctor is the same as the first occurrence or 77 if the doctor is different than the first occurrence.

In the above example, the desired result is:

```
Patient_id  Test_date_time      Doctor_id    Code
----------  ------------------  ---------   -------
123         4/2/2012  08:00 AM  SMITH_J     
123         4/2/2012  12:01 PM  SMITH_J     76
123         4/3/2012  11:00 AM  SMITH_J     
123         5/1/2012  10:00 AM  SMITH_J
123         5/1/2012  07:00 PM  SMITH_J     76
123         5/1/2012  08:00 PM  JONES_B     77
123         5/1/2012  10:00 PM  SMITH_J     76
```

The Test_date_time field is formatted as a Date/Time field. The table is not sorted by the date_time field. The Patient_id is a number unique to the patient and Doctor_id is a string unique to the doctor.

I'm not even sure where to start or how to store the information to compare dates. Any ideas how I could attack this sort of situation?

Comment: Out of curiosity what if you had `123 5/1/2012  7:00 PM  SMITH_J` would you have one record with 76 and another with 77 on 5/1?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I'll add the row to show this situation, too!

Comment: @HansUp: Any time a doctor reads the same test on the same day it is code 76. I've updated the table with this example. The Patient_id and Test_date _should_ be unique, but it is not absolutely not guaranteed. If it did happen, it would indicate some kind of glitch in how the computer logged the test, since a patient cannot be in two places at the same time for the same procedure.

Comment: If you're curious, you can see a brief discussion of these codes and how they are used here: [76 and 77 Modifier](http://www.aapc.com/memberarea/forums/showthread.php?t=15497).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query will determine if you need a 76 or 77 value for code for a given `{Patient_id, Test_Date_type`}

Sadly this can't be used in an [updatable query](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;116142&Produc). As the MSDN article suggests you have two options. 1) Loop through the results updating each record or inserting the results into a temp table and then use that temp table to do the update.

```
SELECT Ptests.Patient_id, 
       Ptests.Test_date_time, 
       Iif(SeventySixers.Patient_id IS NULL, 77, 76) AS Code 
FROM   (PTests 
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT MAX(Test_date_time) AS last_date_time, 
                          Patient_id 
                   FROM   PTests AS t1 
                   GROUP  BY Datevalue(test_date_time), 
                             Patient_id, 
                             Doctor_id 
                   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) AS SeventySixers 
          ON ( PTests.Test_date_time = SeventySixers.last_date_time ) 
             AND ( PTests.Patient_id = SeventySixers.Patient_id )) 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT MAX(Test_date_time) AS last_date_time, 
                         Patient_id 
                  FROM   PTests AS t1 
                  GROUP  BY Datevalue(test_date_time), 
                            Patient_id 
                  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) AS SeventySevens 
         ON ( PTests.Test_date_time = SeventySevens.last_date_time ) 
            AND ( PTests.Patient_id = SeventySevens.Patient_id ) 
WHERE  (( NOT ( SeventySixers.Patient_id ) IS NULL )) 
        OR (( NOT ( SeventySevens.Patient_id ) IS NULL ));
```

---

Create and insert statements used for testing

```
CREATE TABLE [PTests]
    ([Patient_id] int, [Test_date_time] datetime, [Doctor_id] varchar(7), [Code] int);

INSERT INTO [PTests]
    ([Patient_id], [Test_date_time], [Doctor_id], [Code])
VALUES
    (123, #2012-04-02 08:00:00#, 'SMITH_J', null);

INSERT INTO [PTests]
    ([Patient_id], [Test_date_time], [Doctor_id], [Code])
VALUES
    (123, #2012-04-02 12:01:00#, 'SMITH_J', null);

INSERT INTO [PTests]
    ([Patient_id], [Test_date_time], [Doctor_id], [Code])
VALUES
    (123, #2012-04-03 11:00:00#, 'SMITH_J', null);

INSERT INTO [PTests]
    ([Patient_id], [Test_date_time], [Doctor_id], [Code])
VALUES
    (123, #2012-05-01 10:00:00#, 'SMITH_J', null);


INSERT INTO [PTests]
    ([Patient_id], [Test_date_time], [Doctor_id], [Code])
VALUES
    (123, #2012-05-01 19:00:00#, 'SMITH_J', null);

INSERT INTO [PTests]
    ([Patient_id], [Test_date_time], [Doctor_id], [Code])
VALUES
    (123, #2012-05-01 20:00:00#, 'JONES_B', null);
```

Answer (score 0):

A query like this will get filter the entries down to where a patient has multiple rows on the same day:

```
SELECT source.*
    FROM Table1 as source
      left join table1 as joined
         on source.patient_id = joined.patient_id 
           and DateValue(source.test_date_time) = DateValue(joined.test_date_time)
           and source.test_date_time <> joined.test_date_time
      WHERE joined.patient_id is not null
```

This gives:

```
Patient_id  Test_date_time          Doctor_id    Code           
----------  ------------------      ---------   -------           
123         5/2/2012 1:05:00 AM     smith_j 
123         5/2/2012 12:50:00 AM    smith_j     76
123         5/1/2012 10:00:00 AM    smith_j 
123         5/1/2012 8:00:00 PM     jones_b     77
```

Then you would need some sort of procedural code to iterate over the query results (RecordSet) and assign a 76 or 77 to the rows based on the comparison to the first occurence of the doctor_id value.

You would probably want to do a filter or GROUP BY on the patient_ID and the DatePart(test_date_time) in your recordset to make sure you don't step into other patients/days in your iteration.